# Change native View with Cordova Webview/Phonegap Button onclick (eventlistener)

Tags: javascript, objective-c, events, cordova

I'm using Cordova in a Native application. When the User is finished uploading a Level on my Server, he can choose want he wants to do next. Now he should be able start a Game directly out of the Cordova Webviewer, by Clicking a Button "Start Level Now!".

The new Level will be Downloaded and startet in another ViewController.

How can I listen to the onclick Event of the Button in my native Code to Perform a Segue on my PlayLevelVievcontroller.m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write a plugin.

then call
onclick="plugin.callNative(['arguments'])"

then
the cordova calls your own native class.

```
var myplugin = {
    performSegue: function (arguments) {
        var callback = function () {};
        cordova.exec(callback, callback, "nativeClass", "nativeMethod",arguments);
    }
};
```

and declare your native class and method like this

```
@interface MyPlugin : CDVPlugin

- (void)myNativeMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)urlCommand;

@end
```

and implement your native class like this

```
- (void)myNativeMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)urlCommand
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSArray *arguments = urlCommand.arguments;
if (Arguments are not right) {

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];

} else {
    // Do something
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
}

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:urlCommand.callbackId];
```

}